# List.filter and List.mem

Tags: ocaml

I am having a problem understanding this particular line

```
let lst = ["a", "b", "c"];
List.filter (fun (a, _b) -> not (List.mem a lst)) assoc
```

Comment: What specifically do you have problem understanding? Do you understand what `List.filter` and `List.mem` does individually? If not, have you read the documentation? Is there something in the documentation that is unclear?

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation. I just got confused on how to evaluate them together. Thanks.

Comment: Another tip is that you can run this, and other experiments, in the toplevel on your own computer or [online](https://try.ocamlpro.com/) to see what it actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List.filter` takes a function that takes each element in the list in turn and returns a boolean. If the boolean value is true, the element is part of the returned list.

In this case, any tuple in `assoc` whose first element is not in `lst` is returned as a new list.

Consider:

```
let lst = ["a"; "b"; "c"]
let assoc = [("a", 42); ("g", 27)]

let filtered = List.filter (fun (a, _) -> not @@ List.mem a lst) assoc
(* [("g", 27)] *)
```